# How to change default new folder name without parentheses and spaces?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-11, files-folders

As you all know, when you make new folder, its name is `New folder`. If you add second folder, `New folder (2)`. I want to change it with `newnew` and i have changed it successfully with registry changes(via instructions on [winaero](https://winaero.com/how-to-change-default-new-folder-name-in-windows-11/)). In summary, i added a key called `NamingTemplates` on `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer` and added string value called `RenameNameTemplate` and filled it with "newnew".

But also i want to change it `newnew2`, `newnew3`, instead of `newnew (2)`, `newnew (3)`. I.e without parentheses and spaces.

How can i do?

Answer (score 1):

Windows Explorer cannot be customized for that.
You need to use a third-party tool.
I use here the free [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/).

The following script will map
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>
to create a new folder inside the current folder:

```
newname=newnew         ; this is the folder's prefix string
^n::                   ; map ctrl-N
Z = 0
Loop
{
    Z++
    Path := GetActiveExplorerPath()
    CandidateName = %Path%\%newname%%Z%
    IfNotExist, %CandidateName%
    {
         FileCreateDir, %CandidateName%
         break
    }
}
return

GetActiveExplorerPath()
{
    explorerHwnd := WinActive("ahk_class CabinetWClass")
    if (explorerHwnd)
    {
        for window in ComObjCreate("Shell.Application").Windows
        {
            if (window.hwnd==explorerHwnd)
                return window.Document.Folder.Self.Path
        }
    }
}
```

After installing AutoHotKey, put the above text in a `.ahk` file and
double-click it to test. You may stop the script by right-click on
the green H icon in the traybar and choosing Exit. To have it run on login,
place it in the Startup group at
`C:\Users\USER-NAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`.

Useful AutoHotkey documentation:

- [List of Keys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm)
- [Hotkeys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm)